# Removing horizontal scan lines from video?

Tags: video, cleaning

I recorded some supposedly 720p video on my phone which usually yields nice results. However something about the conditions of how it was set up has resulted in the whole sequence having these lines that flicker and run up the screen as if its trying to adjust to the lighting repeatedly, I'm sure its this because as I move around in the video occasionally blocking the light it stops but returns when I unshadow the area that is been filmed.

I have the Adobe CS5 suite which includes Premier but I only know a few basic functions. Is there anything in there I can use to filter this out? Ultimately I'd like to convert the video to youtube so I don't mind a bit of format loss.

TIA

Youtube clip of the offending lines:

Comment: Could you show an example of how these lines actually look?

Comment: I tried to capture a screen shot of it but I couldn't it's to quick. Short of uploading the video I don't think I could. I'm just about to start trying random settings in premier to see if I can remove it.

Comment: This may be subject dependent, a subject with inherent lines like a fence or pin stripe shirt that are the source of the interference. If you can not show the subject, how about your best shot at describing it?

Comment: I've added a clip of what I'm trying to describe.

Comment: I wouldn't describe those as lines. Looks like a sync issue with your lighting, do you use fluorescent lamps?

Comment: No its just natural sun light. Anyway to adjust for such issues?

Answer (score 2):

If your video was shot indoors with fluorescent lamps illuminating the room, then the lines will be due to the frequency of the camera's shutter being similar to the frequency of the lights flickering on and off (usually 50Hz in UK, 60Hz in US).

It's not really possible to fix this in post production. You'd need to reshoot with different lighting or at a different shutter speed on the camera.

See link below for more info:

http://www.davidsatz.com/aboutflicker_en.html